# GraphQL schema Parser

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

To find the way how to build request generator for GraphQL is it possible to build schema analytical instrument for building interactive form working with GraphQL endpoint?
Maybe someone know already exists?
On PHP or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for form editor based on graphql introspection possibilities. Of course it's easily doable for simple cases. Real problems you can have with f.e. referential selects.

You can tak inspiration from [react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin), which automatically builds admin UIs based on REST API but can utilize [graphql](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphcool) and many other data sources.

You can also play with dockerized [API Platform](https://api-platform.com) (php) but it's [admin](https://github.com/api-platform/admin) (react-admin/admin-on-rest) uses Hydra specs.